# app delegate shows error displaying table view in main screen

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I am creating a news app with table view which doesn't show up and acting with a thread error,
can you please tell me,
how do I solve the thread error as shown in here?
I just want the app to work smoothly...

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        let homeViewController = HomeViewController()
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: homeViewController)
        let window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        
        window.rootViewController = navigationController
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        return true
    }
```

btw I apologize if the way on writing my question is bit wrong, as I am on hurry...
thanks

[this the thread error is shown in app delegate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6W194.jpg)

Comment: are you using storyboard as well ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using storyboard you need to initialise controller like this

```
 let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let homeViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as! HomeViewController
```

If you are not using Storyboard you need to delete it and remove that from `plist`

Answer (score 0):

**There is something issue on Storyboard, Please check the Main.storyboard(storyboard where your home view controller screen exists) file exists in your project or not. Also, I have changed the code for the delegate window. Now you can use as follows:-**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    let homeViewController = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as! HomeViewController
    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: homeViewController)
    window?.rootViewController = navigationController
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
}
```

**Add these variable initializers in App delegate file**

```
var window: UIWindow?
```

Comment: Why do you get `AppDelegate` instance inside `AppDelegate`?

Comment: First of all, I was to use delegate variable, but it's also declared under the method of didFinishWithLaunch so it's an extra declaration, I will edit it.